# $G$ is a cyclic p-group where $H \le G$ and $K \le G$. Prove that $H \le K$ or $K \le H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

The question is: $G$ is a cyclic p-group where $H \le G$ and $K \le G$.  Prove that $H \le K$ or $K \le H$.

I think I can prove this, but I am not sure if my logic is correct.

$|G| = |<g>| = p^{k}$ where $p$ is some prime and $k \ge 1$ because G is a cyclic p-group.  I know that $G$ must have a unique subgroup for every divisor of $p^{k}$ because $G$ is cyclic.

$|H| = p^{k_1}$ and $|K| = p^{k_2}$ where $k_2 > k_1$ because of Lagrange's Theorem.  Additionally, $H$ and $K$ are unique subgroups as stated earlier.

We also know that $p^{k_1}$ divides $p^{k_2}$, hence, $K$ has a unique subgroup of order $p^{k_1}$ since $K$ is also cyclic.  That subgroup must be $H$ as every subgroup of $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, and also every subgroup of a particular order is unique.

Thus, $H \le K$.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is correct. Good job!